# Large strings added to a text box freezing my program

Tags: c#, memory, textbox, streamreader

This program opens files into a textbox. It works fine with small files such as 4KB in size, but I am having trouble with a 200KB file. Ideally, I want to be able to open files of any size, but opening large files into a text box freezes the program. What am I doing wrong?

```
        private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                Text = openFileDialog1.FileName + " - " + "Fixprt";
                textBox1.Text = String.Empty;

                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    textBox1.Text += sr.ReadLine() + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                sr.Close();
            }
            openFileDialog1.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: Why not load it all at once? For example: `textbox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);` Or you can read all lines, `string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);` and then use `lines` to do what you want.

Comment: That freezes the program regardless of file size

Comment: concatenating a string in a loop is a bad idea, at the very least you shoud use a StringBuilder.  Also why not make it async.

Comment: @cd5ssmffan it's standard behaviour, what do you expect when loading this data on the UI? One of the issues is, the actual Text property does a check behind the scene to determine if the new value *is not the same as the current value*... when doing this, possibly thousands of times, it is an issue; do it once, don't rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Reading file line-by-line gives unwanted overhead. It would be better to read all file at once.
2. Consider to use async/await. This will bring you more responsive interface.

So I would suggest the next solution:

```
    private async void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            Text = openFileDialog1.FileName + " - " + "Fixprt";

            textBox1.Text = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();

            sr.Close();
        }
        openFileDialog1.Dispose();
    }
```

**Edit**

As discussed in the comments, this solution doesn't correctly process unix-style line breaks. For this case it can be other decision:

```
   private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            Text = openFileDialog1.FileName + " - " + "Fixprt";

            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(sr.ReadLine());
            }
            textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();

            sr.Close();
        }
        openFileDialog1.Dispose();
    }
```

Now we are using [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8), which is designed for fast processing of string data.

Comment: Thanks, this fixes the problem. However, line breaks in the text files are being ignored

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ, yes, using the visual element will cause additional timings, but it can be a part of task which TS needs to solve - some text editor etc.

Comment: @cd5ssmffan, it is strange -  I tested it on several files and all the breaks remains untouched.

Comment: Because you're adding breaks in your code above, this answer doesnt... Again, read my comments, that's why they are there.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ no, I am not

Comment: This is what the file looks like in notepad++: https://i.imgur.com/UMXA0wd.png and this is what happens when I open the file in my program: https://i.imgur.com/eDLmPzN.png

Comment: `textBox1.Text += sr.ReadLine() + Environment.NewLine;` what do you think that line is doing?

Comment: Can you share your file anywhere? I want to "play" with it.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I am using this code `textBox1.Text = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();`

Comment: I loaded your file in the test project and received: https://imgur.com/mtfhiBT . Could it be this file comes from Unix?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. I'm on windows 10. I have tested another file (https://pastebin.com/SGtdBXxj) and it displayed it properly with line breaks. Initially, I thought this was a file size issue, but then I tested a file even smaller than this one, and line breaks did not display properly. Only https://pastebin.com/SGtdBXxj is properly displayed for some reason

Comment: I mean it can be issue when you try to load a file generated on a PC under Linux OS, for example. Window, Linux and Macs uses different symbols for line breaks - you can see it in Notepade++ menu under `Edit-EOL conversion` item.

Comment: I understand now, thanks. These files are automatically generated by a C++ program on windows. all of them are set to unix except for this one (perhaps I changed it when saving the file somehow). Is there a way to get linux and mac line breaks to work too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210005/discussion-between-cd5ssmffan-and-miamy).